# How to reset Excel 2016 to default settings

Tags: microsoft-excel

I changed some settings in Excel so that I treated percentages as decimals. it worked great for that one specific project, but now I can't remove this configuration, and all my columns across all projects past and current are having their values divided by hundred.

This is incredibly annoying, and is making Excel usable for me.
I've tried reinstalling it and deleting the REGEDIT values for Excel, but still it persists.

Can somebody please help me fix my Excel?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option on the Advanced tab of Options in Excel to Automatically insert a decimal point. 
[image: Advanced edition option to insert decimal]

I haven't tested if this affects display of previously saved workbooks but it does seem to affect all new numeric entries in all workbooks after it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this :

- Go into Control Panel / Programs and Features.
- Right-click on your Microsoft Office version.
- Choose `Change`
- Choose `Quick Repair` and click `Repair`.
- If that didn't work, do the same but choose `Online Repair`.
- If nothing works, uninstall and reinstall Office.

Comment: I've tried to do the things you asked. Repairs and reinstalls, still whenever I open a document it treats all my numbers as decimals. And all cells are divided by 100

Comment: Uninstall using the [following instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8), option 1 followed by option 2, then reinstall. If no go, repeat but do the uninstall using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_full_version_history.html).

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate solution is, to use Microsoft Fixit tool. Hit this link to download and Run the Wizard to fix the issue.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/0/C/B0C6EEE0-47D4-47FD-AA50-CABAA515D0D8/MicrosoftFixit50274.msi

Comment: It says my version of Excel is not supported?

Comment: Wait for while, I'll back to you. Which Version of Windows you are using?

Comment: The title may have been misleading, I'm using Microsoft Office 365 on the newest update.

Comment: No since long I'm using that Version of Fixit  and never got any such error but mine is 2013 & 2016 on different drives.

Comment: You try this https://fix-it-center.en.softonic.com/download?ex=REG-60.2 is Version:Beta 1.0.0080.0 .

Answer (score 0):

These following small changes in Excel program shortcut link could allow you to easily reset Excel 2016 settings.

If Excel shortcut doesn't exist yet on your PC's desktop then create it like [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-an-office-program-or-file-9a8df64b-cd87-4700-95cc-4bc3e2a962da).

Else you could also find it in folder **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs** .

Once this shortcut created or founded then make a right click on it, select properties and in target field add the option **/unregserver** as follows:

for the 64-bit version of Office 2016:
**"C:\Program files\Microsoft Office\Office\Excel.exe" /unregserver**

Or as follows for the 32-bit version of Office 2016:
**"C:\Program files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office\Excel.exe" /unregserver**

That's all. Good luck

Comment: can I still do this if I don't have admin rights?